# How can I verify a job offer is legitimate

Tags: job-offer

I have checked out the company they say they represent and I believe Amerigroup is legitimate.  However, I question that the Online interviewer actually works for this company as stated.  They offered the position after an online interview and stated I should join them online at 8 a.m. the next morning (10/28/16) and that I would be working at home until they completed a facility in my area...they would send me a check to purchase what software I would need to perform the job from home.  When I checked the company out they have offices in West Palm, Fort Lauderdale and Orlando, FL  I am in Stuart, FL which is about 45 minutes from West Palm.  Just doesn't feel right!

Comment: [Quite similar, but not quite a duplicate](http://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/3831/how-can-i-determine-if-an-ad-for-an-unusually-high-paying-job-is-a-scam)

Comment: So why haven't you contacted Amerigroup directly and asked them to confirm the interviewer's claims? VTC.

Comment: What is the job you would be doing?

Comment: Nij, I went online to do just that and can't find a number to call.  When you click on careers it directs you to Anthems, they do not list the job as one they have open.

Answer (score 1):

If the job is something like processing payments, it is probably a well-known [money-laundering or similar scam](http://fraudaid.com/ScamSpeak/Nigerian/check_processing_scam.htm).

I would independently look up the phone number for the company (ignore what the interviewer gave you). Phone them and ask to speak to HR. I would explain the situation and ask them if they can confirm the job offer over the phone - and in writing too.

Never phone from a landline directly after receiving a call from the interviewer, they can hold the line open and pretend to be whoever (e.g. a bank or an employer) they told you to phone. Use a different phone or call a relative or friend whose voice you recognise first, then make the important calls after 30 minutes.

Never forget that a check can bounce weeks after it is credited to your account (after it appears to have "cleared") - you will be left owing the bank money. The people who sold you the special software they say you need, are the ones who benefit from this sort of scam.

---

Other references

- [Look for These Five Key Phrases to Identify a Work at Home Scam](http://www.ivetriedthat.com/2010/03/25/look-for-these-five-key-phrases-to-identify-a-work-at-home-scam/)

Comment: calling a relative wont guarantee that they are off the line as they could use the number you dialed on a 2nd line of theirs and join the 2 calls.

Answer (score 1):

If it sounds too good to be true, then it probably is. The red flags for me are:

- It is implied in your question that you didn't apply to them, but they got in touch with you. Unless a recruitment consultant or someone you know makes contact with you, then it is unlikely to be legitimate
- Not meeting a real person, face-to-face for interview is a big red flag. Even if someone reaches out to you electronically, then it is best to meet the hiring manager face-to-face before accepting an offer
- Offering that you work from home is unusual. I've been fighting to work from home with my employers for 7 years now, and they haven't budged an inch. Working from home is a red flag here, because it may imply that there isn't a real office or a real business involved
- Offering to send you a cheque to buy equipment just sounds wrong