# How to avoid being cheated by some fake recruiters as a newbie?

Tags: job-search, recruitment, india, fraud

Currently I'm searching for job in IT as a fresher.
I registered on many job portals like [Monster.com](http://www.monsterboard.com), [naukri.com](https://www.naukri.com/) and a few others.

I have been receiving calls from various local job consultancies. Which are mainly spammers as far as I know.

Yesterday I received a call for direct interview in some of the top MNCs.
I shared that with my elder brother who suggested me to be aware of the frauds. And after searching their number I realized that they were faking.

How to avoid being cheated by spam companies (as they are getting common in the region I live in)?

The basic purpose of this question is to know if there are some basic things that every company should have and a newbie should know as They are more susceptible to forgery ?

Comment: Apply with the company? I'm not sure what other answer you're looking for here. We have numerous other questions on identifying scams or dishonest recruiters.

Comment: My question is how to apply without being scammed ,being a fresher I don't have the experience to judge a company. @Lilienthal

Comment: You want to apply to "top MNCs" without knowing what that means? Voting to close as unclear what you're asking.

Comment: @IshanMahajan "how to apply without being scammed" - the best thing is to be on the lookout for it, which it sounds like you are since you already identified one scammer.

Comment: Possible duplicates: "[How to ask a multinational company if a job offer is not a scam?](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/28097/how-to-ask-a-multinational-company-if-a-job-offer-is-not-a-scam)" and "[How can I determine if an ad for an unusually high-paying job is a scam?](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/3831/how-can-i-determine-if-an-ad-for-an-unusually-high-paying-job-is-a-scam)

Comment: You were essentially asking two questions. I have edited your question so that only the 'avoid spammers' remains, because that is the best one answerable. Your question is still broad, though. Can you narrow it down? You should also [edit] and name your 'region.' Your comment replies (like the first one under the answer) should be in your question too - comments disappear.

Comment: If you don't respond to any recruiters, you can't be cheated.

Answer (score 13):

- Apply directly on the company's website.
- On job sites, apply through internal recruiters, that is, recruiters who are direct employees of the company.
- Apply through reputed third-party recruitment agencies.

Comment: I have learned from my college seniors that you'll need a reference to have your resume even considered and its hard withou references

Comment: Find better advisors then. 14 of my last 20 interviews have come through the above methods, with the others coming through references. You asked for methods without using references, so I gave you the options. If you already "know" that you cannot get interviews without references, then what exactly do you want to hear here?

Comment: I am a fresher so I am confused and afraid of being cheated.And I'll try your suggestions.

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by being "cheated". The worst that could happen is you show up at the company's office for an interview and the security guard sends you away because you have a bogus interview invitation. There is very less likelihood of that happening anyway because in case of big MNCs, the interview invitation is sent by the company's employee, not the consultancy. That aside, I am rather amused to learn that a fresher can declare a consultancy fake with absolute certainty by just searching their number.

Comment: You are not aware of the frauds here in the regions I live in.People fake to be a new established co. and then lure people searching jobs into paying for confirming their jobs.

Comment: So only apply to companies that are at least a year old (or 2, or 5) and never pay a company you're applying for. Since you're already aware of these risks, what exactly is the problem?

Comment: @Ishan A company asking money for a job is clearly a fraud, and if you are already aware of that, then all you have to do is back off and refuse to pay. How will you get cheated then? "You are not aware of the frauds here in the regions I live in." I am Indian, I am more aware of the frauds than you.

Comment: @IshanMahajan Furthermore, we can hardly help on a matter (specificly the cheating) that you don't describe and known only in your vicinity. I think the answer is good enough for your question. Please specify further the question, or trust the answer.

Comment: @Sonic The original question that I answered was "How to apply at top MNCs without references?" Now the question has been edited to something totally different, rendering my answer kinda relevant. Nonetheless, given that *OP himself* seems to be unclear about his issue, I don't feel any special inclination to edit the answer.

Comment: @MaskedMan I mean, your answer is still good for the current question. How to not get fooled at looking for job? Yeah, apply directly on a validated page or via validated 3rd party. It fits well. Ishan is putting himself into the fray with registering on the portal. To avoid that, he shouldnt use the portal, but use some more direct channel. I don't have any single problem with your answer. Did I sound like that? I asked Ishan to consider it as valid answer, or to specify his question more.

Comment: @Sonic Oh no, not at all, it didnt sound like you had a problem with the answer. I got a notification due to your comment, and that was when I noticed the question has changed. So I thought I should explain for future readers to get some context why the answer seems to be not entirely focussed on the question.

Answer (score 1):

To contribute more to the discussion, I am mentioning the red flags being noticed by me while I was at a fake consulting firm for a job.

1. Neither the main entrance of the office nor the reception had any
   mention of the Consultancy name.
2. I noticed the team of HRs were dressed in formals and were
   getting forms filled from other interviewees.
3. I was asked to put my phone on silent mode so I did that but retained my focus on the surroundings.
4. I saw a dude coming out of the Interview room and he specifically looked at me and said something while exiting (which I understood later).
5. I entered the HR’s cabin. There was a company name board in this room behind the HR but it was partially covered by the curtain.
6. After Round 1, money came into the picture and I was asked to deposit an amount of INR 3500 to carry on with the next round. Obviously, nobody carries such an amount in their wallets during the interview. So, I was asked to withdraw it from a nearby ATM.
7. If you are given a person to accompany you till ATM, beware as something is fishy. I asked the guy for directions but he insisted on accompanying me downstairs.

NOTE: None of the MNCs in India charge money from the job seekers rather they charge it from the consultancy. If you are asked to pay for anything, feel free to step out.

Comment: If you are asked to pay for anything, do not "feel free to step out": instead **run away as fast as your little legs will carry you**, you're already in trouble.

Comment: All of this up to point 6 seems pretty normal. But asking the applicant for money is the real red flag. No reputable company would ever do that. If someone claims that you need to pay them money to get a job, they are lying.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you're waiting for people to contact you. I'm unsure how job searching works in India but I'd imagine *you* go to *them* and *they* call you back if they're interested.

So basically, apply with your resume, have a good, current call back number and any contact info, then wait. Apply to multiple places for best result.